# How do you support different view for different platforms in Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

If I am developing an application for iOS and android, is there a possibility in Titanium alloy mvc framework to maintain 2 different views for the same controller for the 2 different platforms (iOS and android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep it is possible to have different views for iOS and Android platform. You have to just **create nested directory(namely android, ios or mobileweb) under views directory**.

Example to structure directories followed:

```
--app
   |
   --views
   |   |
   |   --ios
   |   |  |
   |   |  --index.xml     //ios related xml
   |   --android
   |      |
   |      --index.xml     //android related xml
   --controllers
   |   |
   |   --index.js     //common controller for index.xml
   --styles
       |
       --index.tss     //common style for index.xml
```

*More info in [Titanium Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Concepts-section-34636240_AlloyConcepts-Platform-SpecificResources)*

Comment: Thanks... I just didn't see that in the documentation :)